# Read more display extra content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a solution. For example in this pen ( [codepen](https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA) ) is shown a read more and read less. But how can i achieve this with html tag inside the content?

For example, in the class more i have set the `<p>` and in the other more class i have an element closing the `</p>`

```
<span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectiusmod tempor <p> Lorem sdfd sf dds sd sd
</span>
<br><br>
<div class="more">
  Morbi placerat </p> imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
</div>
```

Comment: Where does your `p` start and end? It seems it is spanning multiple elements?

Comment: That isn't valid html shown. Putting a closing `<p>` there will break the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best approach toward the problem but I have encountered in a project before and I did this way:

On click of a button launch this script:

```
$(".more2").contents().appendTo('.more1')
```

Your HTML can look this:

```
<span class="more1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectiusmod tempor <p> Lorem sdfd sf dds sd sd
</span>
<br><br>
<div class="more2">
  Morbi placerat </p> imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
</div>
```